# using PHP and curl to get the result from api

Tags: php, json, curl

i have to do a curl request to get som data from an api.
i stuck with ideas how to do this right. or just monday tired ;)

url is like = .../api/web/timezon

And its json build
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

what i want to get from it is:
Version and Content

so, how do i do this as smooth as possible?

Heres my example code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://servername/api/web/TimeZones");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'x-ms-company-registerid: x-ms-company-registerid',
    'Accept: application/json',
    'Content-Type:     application/json')                                                                       
);
    $parsed_json = curl_exec($ch);
    $parsed_json = json_decode($parsed_json);

foreach($parsed_json->results->collection1 as $collection){
    echo $collection->Version->text . '<br>';
    echo $collection->Content->text . '<br>';
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted ?

Comment: dont get your question :(

Comment: sorry, the problem i have right now is that i wont get any result... it just get me a blank page.

Comment: and looking at the server side logs, everything is ok?